# org.osate.xtext.aadl2.Activator cannot be found by org.osate.xtext.aadl2_1.0.0.qualifier error occured

Tags: java, xtext, emf

I am  trying to use  `com.google.inject.Injector` class in `AADL` which is a domain specific language created using EMF and `XText`. when i call function `Aadl2StandaloneSetup.doSetup()` which provides `Initialisation` support for running `Xtext` languages without equinox extension registry, I get error  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osate.xtext.aadl2.Activator` cannot be found by `enter code here`org.osate.xtext.aadl2_1.0.0.qualifier. how can this be fixed.

Code of `Aadl2StandaloneSetup.doSetup()` is below:

```
public Injector createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration() {
org.osate.xtext.aadl2.properties.PropertiesStandaloneSetup.doSetup();
Injector injector = createInjector();
        register(injector);
        return injector;
    }

public Injector createInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new org.osate.xtext.aadl2.Aadl2RuntimeModule());
    }

public void register(Injector injector) {

org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceFactory resourceFactory = injector.getInstance(org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceFactory.class);
        org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceServiceProvider serviceProvider = injector.getInstance(org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceServiceProvider.class);
        Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("aadl", resourceFactory);
        org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("aadl", serviceProvider);
        Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("aadl2", resourceFactory);
        org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("aadl2", serviceProvider);

}
```

Comment: i tried to and activator.java class to org.osate.xtext.aadl2 package. now it is showing errors Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.IScopeProvider was bound.
  at org.eclipse.xtext.service.DefaultRuntimeModule.configureLinkingIScopeProvider(DefaultRuntimeModule.java:152)

2) No implementation for org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.IScopeProvider was bound.
  at org.eclipse.xtext.service.DefaultRuntimeModule.configureSerializerIScopeProvider(DefaultRuntimeModule.java:148)

Comment: this makes no sense. standalonesetups are for standalone. activators for eclipse. can you give more context of what you try to do. don you have a binding of IScopeProvider somewhere?

Comment: it might be that the dsl you use was written in a way that it does not work standalone

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how see if i have binding of IScopeProvider somewhere. I am trying to call a function Injector injector = IResourceServiceProvider.Registry.INSTANCE.getResourceServiceProvider(URI.createFileURI("dummy.aadl")).get(Injector.class); which in turn require me to first call Aadl2StandaloneSetup.doSetup(); functon. but it is showing the above mentioned errors

Comment: Have a look at what the Xtext new project wizard does. I have no idea what your dsl does differently